# SQLITE return only matching consecutive row using WHERE

Tags: android, sqlite

My Android sqlite db has two fields plus _id and I am looking for an SQL query that includes this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table WHERE datetime>? AND datetime<? AND value=1 ORDER BY datetime ASC
```

but would only return rows or count where value=1, consecutively for 4 minutes

```
datetime                value
...
2014-11-21 11:00:00     0
2014-11-21 11:01:00     0
2014-11-21 11:02:00     1
2014-11-21 11:03:00     1
2014-11-21 11:04:00     0
2014-11-21 12:05:00     0
2014-11-21 11:06:00     1
2014-11-21 11:07:00     1
2014-11-21 11:08:00     1
2014-11-21 11:09:00     1
2014-11-21 11:10:00     0
...
```

Using the example data above it should only returned a count of 4, 4 consecutive rows not all 6 where value=1:

```
2014-11-21 11:06:00     1
2014-11-21 11:07:00     1
2014-11-21 11:08:00     1
2014-11-21 11:09:00     1
```

Is this possible with SQL and just the two fields, and if so any clues as to how?

(And if it makes any difference my datetime data is being held as long milliseconds)

Comment: This is possible in SQL, but complex and inefficient. Can't you just drop the rows you do not want when you are reading the result?

Comment: I actually only need a count or true/false if value=1 for more than 4 minutes.

Comment: So what is the desired output for this example data?

Comment: A count of what exactly? Please show the desired output for this example data.

Comment: a count (or returned rows) of how many rows where there has been 4 minutes of consecutive value=1, between start and end time ordered by datetime ASC

Comment: In your example, would that be 1 or 4? And how should a range of length 8 be counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent some time pondering on cute way to do your task. I don't think there is efficient way to do it as a query.
So I think you should return to good old cursor and do it like this (and I believe it will be the fastest and the simplest way):

```
SELECT * from table WHERE value=1 ORDER BY datetime
```

And then run through fetched records (in pseudocode):

```
int count=0;
int intervalLen=0;

if (move to first) 
do {
  if(get(value)==1){
    if(intervalLen==4)
      count++;
    intervalLen++;

  } else 
    intervalLen=0;

} while (move to next)
```

**Note** that it counts uninterrupted intervals of value=1 not less than 4 records in a row. 
If you have to consider exact time you should change it a bit

Comment: I came to the same conclusion yesterday, loop, keeping count and resetting when not 1 etc. I tried for some time with INNER queries but could not get it to work correctly. So unless someone else can come up with a neat all in-one SQL query, I'll carry on looping the cursor. Thanks sberezin for your time and coming up with an alternative workable solution.

Comment: I'm also interested if someone will provide query-based solution. Good luck:)